# Building a Rest Server

Tags: java, rest

I've learned how to send and handle Rest API requests, so am reasonably comfortable with how an outside user would submit requests to an API through methods such as opening a connection to the API, setting a request method and processing returned messages.
However the time has come to create my own Rest Web Service, and I'm a bit stuck as I'm not entirely familiar with just how the server will handle the communication.
I can set up a connection just fine to allow for communication, but I'm not particularly comfortable with the specifics of a connection.
Below is the method where I initialise the server, which will then wait until something connects and have a brief conversation until the client disconnects.

```
    public void Initialise(){
        try {
            ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(21); //TODO: Change port?
            while(true){
                Socket incoming = s.accept();
                Runnable r = new ConnectionManager(incoming);
                Thread t = new Thread(r);
                t.start();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

And the class handling the connection.

```
public class ConnectionManager implements Runnable{
private Socket incoming;

public ConnectionManager(Socket i){
    this.incoming = i;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        try{
            //Initialise IOStreams
            InputStream inStream = incoming.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outStream = incoming.getOutputStream();

            Scanner in = new Scanner(inStream);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outStream, true);

            out.println("TODO: Change this message. Press Q to quit.");

            boolean done = false; 
            while (!done && in.hasNextLine()){
                String line = in.nextLine();
                out.println("Echo: " +line);
                if (line.trim().equals("Q")){
                    done = true;
                }
            }
        }
        finally{
            incoming.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

What I'm not sure of how to do, is how I start building an application that listens for Rest requests, and then processes them accordingly. I feel confident that upon examining the connection, I'd be able to engineer functionality to process the API request, however I do not know how to view the specifics of a Rest request sent by a user.
For example, if a user were to send a request, such as

```
GET exampleAPI/endpoint?params
```

**How do I examine the request, and then subsequently process it accordingly?**
For example, on the client side when you initiate the request, an approach such as the use of HttpURLConnection would allow you to follow the process of

```
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) targetURL.openConnection();
c.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Which would allow you to submit a Get request to the target URI.
Looking through the Java Documentation for [Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html), I don't quite know how I can view incoming requests and active connections.
**Am I missing something, or just doing things completely wrong?**

Comment: Why can't you use JAX-WS or Jersy ? Is there a restriction ?

Comment: Not an answer, but I would recommend using a framework for this. They provide functionality for all the things you are trying to write by hand.

Comment: @javaguy No restrictions, I just lack experience in building a Rest server, so am unsure of the best practices and setups.

Comment: @Potatosaurus use an existing Java application server e.g. Jetty, Tomcat, or JBoss. There are many many things that they do for you for free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, you can use Jersey/Spring/etc.. for this rather than you rewriting the logic for the whole server and handling multiple threads, etc..

Also, you should know that there is a `JDK` `API` called `JAX-RS` (specification plus implementation) for the same. you can look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html)

You can look [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) for `Spring REST Controller` or [here](https://jersey.java.net/) for Jersey.

I recommend you go through `JDK JAX-RS API` first, then you may have a look at `Spring and Jersey`.

There are other vendors implementing `JAX-RS`, which you may be interested in, you can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) for comparison for `JAX-RS` implementations.

P.S.: You should also know that `Spring` does not compliant to `JAX-RS API`, rather they have got their own `API`.

Comment: I would add that in Java the most common combination is either Tomcat + a JAX-RS Implementation e.g. Jersey / Jackson or Jetty

Comment: Yes, I agree with you